# imagetoolbar meta tag and IE versions

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer, meta-tags

There are quite a few questions here on SO about the following meta tag not being HTML5 compliant and therefore will not [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) when using `<!DOCTYPE html>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
```

I also know this tag is specifically for one purpose alone: hiding the toolbar that appears when you hover your mouse over any image in Internet Explorer.

However, I could not find out in exactly which versions of Explorer this is applicable.  When I Googled it, most results only mention IE6, but these threads/pages were posted back in 2004.  I'm wondering if that's because the feature was dropped in IE7+.

I do not care about IE6, but if this meta tag is applicable to IE7, IE8, IE9, etc. I'll need to decide if I want to find an alternative method.

**Exactly which versions of Internet Explorer enable the annoying Image Toolbar feature that is disabled via the meta tag above?**

Comment: Can you tell me what plugin produced that line of code?  It is on my wordpress site too, but I cannot find where to remove it. It does not appear to be in any theme files.  Thanks.

Comment: @SherylHohman, my question has nothing to do with WordPress.  That's just an HTML meta tag that anyone can use within their HTML markup.  It's only applicable to IE version 6 and all other browsers will ignore it.  If you have a WordPress plugin or theme that is writing this HTML, then disable them one by one until it goes away.  Otherwise, it's nothing to be very concerned about.

Comment: Thanks. My apologies, and Thanks for your kind and prompt response. I asked a new question as well, but also reached out to you JIC wordpress is where you ran across it, like myself, and happened to remember the source. True. Cleaning up an old site, and *getting carried away with validation*. Also true: Disabling plugins is the way to go if I insist on pursuing. Ignoring it is a much better use of time!! Thanks for pulling my head outta this hole, and Have a great evening.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Apparently, the Image Toolbar was only a feature in IE6.**  It was replaced with the contextual menu (right-click) in subsequent versions.

IE6 is dead so I won't be concerned about not using this meta tag any longer.