# What wordpress plugin generates '<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">' line of code

Tags: wordpress

This line of code appears in the html of my wordpress website.
`<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no"><!-- disable image toolbar (if any) -->`

It is some legacy code relating to images on IE6, and is no longer needed.
It's invalid html, in fact.

I want to remove it, but I cannot find where this line of code was generated.
It does not appear to be in any theme files.

Does anyone know what plugin might have produced that line of code?

Comment: Have you tried running a search through all wp files in your localhost for say <meta http-equiv="Imagetoolbar" or 'imagetoolbar' ? If something is adding it, it should come up.   I just ran that on my localhost with a variety of themes and plugins and gravityforms came up.  (preview.php and print-entry.php)

Comment: ah, no I did not think to search the plugins folder on live site.  I only checked my theme files locally).  Good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the plugin "All In One Wordpress Security" added the code as part of it's "Copy Protection" security setting.

It is located under:
`Dashboard -> WP Security -> Miscellaneous -> Copy Protection..`
`[ ] Check this if you want to disable the "Right Click", "Text Selection" and "Copy" options on the front end of your site.`

As pointed out by @sparky It is not necessary to hunt down references to this line of code or remove it from one's website.
In my case I became obsessed in achieving 100% HTML validation.

As @sparky noted in comments to his [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7207649/5411817) "...It's only applicable to IE version 6 and all other browsers will ignore it."
He also updated his answer to indicate that IE8 and IE7 no longer reference it.

While HTML validation notes it as an "Error", in practical use it is not harmful, and does not necessarily need to be removed.

If you *do* want to remove this code, there are a couple of methods you can use to find where it is being added to your website (assuming WordPress - modify as needed)

- search your `/wp-content/plugins` folder for the term `imagetoolbar` (suggested by @[anmari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440290/anmari))
- disable plugins one by one (or via divide and conquer), empty all caches (including CDN), View Source (or run validator) ... until the code goes away. Or do the same in reverse: Disable everything, then enable to find the culprit.

On my site there were two plugins that *could* add that code were:

- "CornerStone"
- "All In One WP Security & Firewall" (as labeled in the WordPress.org plugins repo),
  ("All In One WP Security" as listed under your site Plugins, and
  "WP Security", as labeled in your Dashboard)
- AnMari notes that "gravityforms" and some themes may also use this code.